# Removing the automatic subtitle of pyplot.pie() on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

slices = [45,20,30]
activities = ['sleeping','eating','working']

plt.pie(slices,startangle=90,labels=activities,shadow=True,autopct='%1.1f%%',colors=['b','g','c'])
plt.axis('equal')

plt.savefig('nomeDaFigura.png')  

plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I just want what comes with the method plt.legend(), it's a pie chart

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the resulting pie chart?

Comment: What subtitle, your figure doesn't seem to have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the `labels` displayed inside your `legend`, then the solution is to not pass them to `pie()`, but instead pass them with your `legend()` call as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

slices = [45, 20, 30]
activities = ['sleeping', 'eating', 'working']

plt.pie(slices, startangle=90, shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%', colors=['b','g','c'])
plt.axis('equal')

plt.savefig('nomeDaFigura.png')  

plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')

plt.legend(labels=activities)
plt.show()
```

This would display your pie chart as follows:

[image: pie with labels only in legend]